# Can two particles be electrically attracted, even when both particles have zero net charges?

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, charge

Can two particles be electrically attracted, even when both particles have zero net charges? Is that possible in some circumstances?

Comment: two dipoles can attract each other despite of the fact that net charge of each of them is zero. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your response, @lesnik. Does it also apply if we upscale it a bit, like an object instead of a particle? For instance, if two objects has no charge, how can we make them electrically attracted to each other?

Comment: An example at the molecular level is van der Waals forces - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force

Answer (score 1):

If two bodies each have zero net charge, attraction is only possible based on uneven distribution of the charges within the bodies.

If we think about dipoles (as suggested in @lesnik's comment), let's say A has two charges A+ and A-, and B has B+ and B-. Then we have 4 attracting/repelling forces:

1. A+ repels B+
2. A+ attracts B-
3. A- attracts B+
4. A- repels B+

The forces depend on the charges involved and the distance (1/d²). So, if we talk about "zero-size" particles, all forces will be equal, just with different signs, thus compensating one another.

But if the dipoles are e.g. arranged in a line, equidistantly A-, A+, B-, B+, then we get

1. A+ repels B+ with -0.25 F (with F being the A+/B- force at unit distance)
2. A+ attracts B- with +1.0 F
3. A- attracts B+ with +0.11111 F
4. A- repels B+ with -0.25 F

We still have alternating positive and negative forces, but their sum now is positive (+0.51111 F).

The magnitude of the effect depends on

- the amount of charge,
- the object distance in relation to the charges displacement inside the bodies.